# Add Boxes created with mdframed to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, mdframed

I am using `mdframed` to create boxes, that have titles and all.

I would like to have a list of these immediately after the table of contents, just like a list of figures, or of tables.

I saw a solution, here: 
[List of Boxes in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262439/list-of-boxes-in-table-of-contents)

But it is way too complicated for me (I am not too skilled), because it seems to use a new environment.

I want to do it in the book environment, but I might need it also for `article` in the future.

Any simple solution out there, before I plunge into the headache of defining new environments?

Thanks!!!

Francesco

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you sticking to `mdframed`? With `tcolorbox` you can make boxes as well, and generating a List of Boxes is ...(pun intended!) straight out of the box ;-)

Comment: The provided solution by Gonzalo Medina in the link above seems to be what you request. Unless you don't show us what you have done so far it's hard to tell what a possible solution will be. And most likely you mean `book` class, not `book`. environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the `startcode` option of `mdframed` and apply an `\addcontentsline` with `\mdf@frametitle` which is defined to hold the content of the `frametitle` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter


\newmdenv[startcode={\addcontentsline{mdbox}{section}{\mdf@frametitle}}]{myenv}





\newcommand{\listofboxes}{%
  \section*{List of Boxes}
  \@starttoc{mdbox}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listofboxes

\clearpage

\begin{myenv}[frametitle={Foo}]
Stuff

\blindtext[5]
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[frametitle={Foobar}]
Other Stuff

\blindtext[2]
\end{myenv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I think I got it!  Yes of course it was class, sorry I wrote fast

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long wait, I was actually writing the text of boxes. So I tried to work out a file similar to the one suggested by Christian, basically using startcode as an option to mdframed (in order not to change all the frames.