# Number boxes and add them to table of contents in mdframed

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, mdframed

I am trying to build an example of text with numbered boxes, that can also be referenced in the table of contents. This example is a mix of the two questions, one of which asked by me: [mdframed boxes in table of content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365305/mdframed-boxes-in-table-of-content).

It seems to me that I should pass the `startinnercode=\addcontentsline{mdbox}{subsection}\mdf@frametitle` command in the `\newenvironment{infobox}`, as an argument of `mdframed`. But I am unable to make it work. Keeping it separate, either I call it with `infobox`, and then I have numbered boxes but not in the ToC, or I call it with `mdframedtoc`, and they are not numbered.

Help appreciated, thanks!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \newcounter{infobox}[chapter]

 \renewcommand{\theinfobox}{\thechapter.\arabic{infobox}}


  \usepackage[framemethod=tikz,rightmargin=5,
  leftmargin=5,backgroundcolor=gray!10,
   frametitlerule=true,frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30,roundcorner=10pt]
  {mdframed}

\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]{%
 \refstepcounter{infobox}
 \begin{mdframed}[%
    frametitle={Infobox \theinfobox\ #1},

]%
 }{%
  \end{mdframed}
 }


\makeatletter
\newmdenv[startinnercode=\addcontentsline{mdbox}{subsection}\mdf@frametitle]
{mdframedtoc}
\newcommand{\listofboxes}{%
 \section*{Liste des focus}
 \@starttoc{mdbox}%
  }
 \makeatother


  \begin{document}

  \tableofcontents
   \listofboxes

   \chapter{Stuff}

   \lipsum[1]

   \begin{infobox}[Sausage]
   \lipsum[2]
    \label{ibx:sausage}
    \end{infobox}

    Infobox \ref{ibx:sausage} says:
      \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{Other Stuff}

  \begin{infobox}[Fried eggs]
  \lipsum[4-5]
  \label{ibx:eggs}
  \end{infobox}

  Infobox \ref{ibx:eggs} says:
  % 
  \lipsum[4]

   \lipsum[5]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `\begin{mdframedtoc}` etc. within `infobox` instead of `\begin{mdframe}` then? If I do so, I get both numbered boxes and entries to the separate `Liste de Focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdframedtoc` environment should be called within the wrapper `infobox`, not `mdframed`. The list entries are generated since `mdframedtoc` does use an `\addcontentsline` as start code and they are numbered, because `infobox` is numbered. The numbering is correct since `infobox` sets the `frametitle` with its numbering scheme.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcounter{infobox}[chapter]

\renewcommand{\theinfobox}{\thechapter.\arabic{infobox}}


\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,rightmargin=5,
leftmargin=5,backgroundcolor=gray!10,
frametitlerule=true,frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30,roundcorner=10pt]
{mdframed}

\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{infobox}
  \begin{mdframedtoc}[%
    frametitle={Infobox \theinfobox\ #1},
    ]%
  }{%
  \end{mdframedtoc}
}


\makeatletter
\newmdenv[startinnercode=\addcontentsline{mdbox}{subsection}\mdf@frametitle]
{mdframedtoc}
\newcommand{\listofboxes}{%
 \section*{Liste des focus}
 \@starttoc{mdbox}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofboxes

\chapter{Stuff}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{infobox}[Sausage]
  \lipsum[2]
  \label{ibx:sausage}
\end{infobox}


\begin{infobox}[Garam Masala]
 A delicious and important spice mixture from India!
 \label{ibx:garammasala}
\end{infobox}

Infobox \ref{ibx:sausage} says:
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Other Stuff}

\begin{infobox}[Fried eggs]
  \lipsum[4-5]
  \label{ibx:eggs}
\end{infobox}

Infobox \ref{ibx:eggs} says:
% 
\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**Update with babel usage**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\newcounter{infobox}[chapter]

\renewcommand{\theinfobox}{\thechapter.\arabic{infobox}}



\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,rightmargin=5,
leftmargin=5,backgroundcolor=gray!10,
frametitlerule=true,frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30,roundcorner=10pt]
{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}



\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{infobox}
  \begin{mdframedtoc}[%
    frametitle={Infobox \theinfobox\ #1},
    ]%
  }{%
  \end{mdframedtoc}
}


\makeatletter
\newmdenv[startinnercode=\addcontentsline{mdbox}{subsection}\mdf@frametitle]
{mdframedtoc}
\newcommand{\listofboxes}{%
 \section*{Liste des focus}
 \@starttoc{mdbox}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofboxes

\chapter{Stuff}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{infobox}[Sausage]
  \lipsum[2]
  \label{ibx-sausage}
\end{infobox}


\begin{infobox}[Garam Masala]
  A delicious and important spice mixture from India!
  \label{ibx-garammasala}
\end{infobox}


Infobox \ref{ibx-sausage} says:
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Other Stuff}

\begin{infobox}[Fried eggs]
  \lipsum[4-5]
  \label{ibx-eggs}
\end{infobox}

Infobox \ref{ibx-eggs} says:
% 
\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! The example worked perfectly fine for me as well! Unfortunately in my original file I have an error message: ! Argument of \tikz@next has an extra } at the first occurence of infobox. It mus be a conflict with some other setting or package I have; I'll try to sort that out commenting each package out in turn. But thanks a lot!

Comment: I found out, for some reason it is incompatible with babel using French as first language. I have no idea why...

Comment: The : used in your labels has a specific meaning in French typography -- either use \shorthands  command or change from : to `-`, for example

Comment: It does not seem to work. But I stop bothering you...

Comment: @FrancescoSaraceno: See my update. Store it as a new file. There is also `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you a thousand times!

Comment: @FrancescoSaraceno: You're welcome! Tiny hint: One can upvote answers additionally to accepting them  ;-)

Comment: @FrancescoSaraceno: Yes, you have ;-)