# List multiple tikz-mdframed boxes like the list of figures, tables and listings

Tags: table-of-contents, mdframed, classicthesis

I'm writing a thesis in which I have created multiple "box environments" for different kind of insights and examples.

I've started from the advance examples of the mdframed documentation with the tikz implementation to create a frame around the title of the main frame.

My three environments have this structure with obviously a change in the \newcounter and \newenvironment names:

```
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newcounter{envpolicy}[part]
\counterwithin{envpolicy}{part}
\newenvironment{envpolicy}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{envpolicy}%
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,font=\color{white},rectangle,fill=mydarkgreen!90]
                {\strut Policy~\theenvpolicy};}}
    }%
    {\mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,font=\color{white},rectangle,fill=mydarkgreen!90]
                {\strut Policy~\theenvpolicy:~#1};}}%
    }%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=mydarkgreen,%
        linewidth=1pt,topline=true,backgroundcolor=mydarkgreen!10,
        frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
    }{\end{mdframed}}
```

The labels, the captions and the general implementation works fine throughout the many different input files of my thesis.

Now to the "problem".

I wanted to add at the beginning of the document a List of policies, List of box 2, List of box 3 and so on.

I currently have a the main ToC, then the list of figures, of tables and of codes. These lists are in the classic-thesis format (not dotted and with the title of list in that particular style).

I've tried searching for some implementation but unsuccessfully.

For example, in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262439/list-of-boxes-in-table-of-contents) (the mdframed method one), I can't figure out where to position the `\addcontentsline{lob}{section}{\numberline{\theinfobox}#1}%`

If I use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445921/mdframed-numbered-subtitles-and-separate-list-of-boxes) (because I want all the list in the same page) I don't know where to place the mdframetoc. In particular the `\begin{mdframedprovatoc}[%` (prova is try in italian :P) now results in the writing **mdframedprovatoc[** immediately before the actual colored box in the main text.

```
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newcounter{prova}[part]
\counterwithin{prova}{part}
\newenvironment{prova}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{prova}%
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
    \begin{mdframedprovatoc}[%
    {\mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,font=\color{white},rectangle,fill=mymaroon!90]
                {\strut prova~\theprova};}}
    }%
    {\mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,font=\color{white},rectangle,fill=mymaroon!90]
                {\strut prova~\theprova:~#1};}}%
    }%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=mymaroon,%
        linewidth=1pt,topline=true,backgroundcolor=mymaroon!10,
        frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
    }{\end{mdframed}\end{mdframedprovatoc}}

\makeatletter
\newmdenv[startinnercode=\addcontentsline{mdprovabox}{subsection}\mdf@frametitle]
{mdframedprovatoc}
\newcommand{\listofprova}{%
    \subsection*{List of Prova}
    \@starttoc{mdprovabox}%
}
\makeatother
```

There is a relatively simple way to implement these tree list of environments without changing too much (I already somehow finished the writings and this is only a minor tweak before submitting and printing...)

Extra: There is a way to show these three list in the same format as classic-thesis list of figures/tables and son on?

Thanks!